# sending multiple send/recv in socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I need bit clarification on using multiple send/recv in socket programs.
My client program looks below(Using TCP SOCK_STREAM).

```
    send(sockfd,"Messgfromlient",15,0);
    send(sockfd,"cli1",5,0);
    send(sockfd,"cli2",5,0);
    send(sockfd,"cli3",5,0);
    send(sockfd,"cli4",5,0);
    send(sockfd,"cli5",5,0);
```

and the server program looks like below.

```
    recv(newsockfd,buf,20,0);
    printf("Buffer is %s\n",buf);
```

when i execute the above program, the output is as below:

Client Msg :Messgfromlient

I believe that the buf size is 20, so only one buffer is getting received.
Adding one more recv on server side.

```
    char buf[20],buf[20];
     ------skipped------
    recv(newsockfd,buf,20,0);
    recv(newsockfd,buf1,20,0);
    printf("Client Msg  :%s\n",buf);
    printf("Client Msg  :%s \n",buf1);
```

output:
1st trial:

```
    Client Msg  :Messgfromlient
    Client Msg  :cli2
```

2nd trail:

```
   Client Msg  :Messgfromlient
   Client Msg  :cli1
```

As we can see that there is some contradiction in the ouputs,
From client side it looks all the msgs are getting sent, but in server, msg will be received based on buf size,here eventhough buf1 has size of 20, why 'cli3''cli4''cli4' msgs are not getting received on buf1?. Is there any specific limit is there? Please clarify on this.

Thanks in Advance,
Raja

Comment: What are the return values from `send()` and `recv()`?  You can't ignore that.

Comment: You are sending buffers of 5 and 15 bytes, but on reception, you are printing strings which terminate with the first `NUL` byte (0x00).  It would probably help if you saved the return values of the `recv()` calls and printed them as well.

Comment: The `len` passed is the max allowed length. `recv` can return a single char or (in non blocking system) a -`1` also. Your "problem" belongs to the process scheduling: it depends on the point of code was executed before the context switch and what the kernel has already dispached.

Comment: 'Using TCP SOCK_STREAM' - think about what that means!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TCP is a byte stream based protocol, it knows nothing about messages. You send `25` bytes in total, and each `recv` on the other side will read *some* of those bytes. You can get 20, you might get `1` and then `19` in the next read, you might get `5` then `4` then `11` then 5. The size parameter to `recv` is the maximum number to read.

You need to loop until you read the whole message yourself, and also understand you might receive more than one "send" in the same received message.

Comment: What happens if e.g. two processes are sending through the same socket at the same time? Will the data be corrupted? Is one `send` blocked until the other `send` finishes?

Answer (score 3):

> the server program looks like below.

```
recv(newsockfd,buf,20,0);
printf("Buffer is %s\n",buf);
```

This is already wrong. It should be:

```
int count = recv(newsockfd,buf,20,0);
if (count == -1)
{
    perror("recv"); // please improve this message
    close(newsocketfd);
}
else if (count == 0)
{
    // peer has closed the connection
    close(newsockfd);
}
else
{
    printf("Buffer is %.*s\n",count,buf);
}
```

This should give you enough of a hint ...

Answer (score 2):

You've got 2 issues:

When you're displaying the results, you're going to stop at the first null byte, which is always after "Messgfromlient". There may be more text already received, but you're not displaying it.

The second issue is that the TCP connection is a stream. You may receive all the data in one go, you may receive only the first byte. You don't know which one is it and can't predict it. You need to handle incomplete reads in your application and you have to handle retries.

You can however make it more likely that all the data will be sent in one packet rather than 6. Have a look at the TCP_CORK option.